# How can my Number or ParseInt() function avoid a string that is not a number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return [1,2,{},3,4]  without using flat()
My code so far

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  
  let myArr= arr 
  .join(" ")
  .replace(/[\s+\W+]/g," ")
  .replace(/\s+/g," ")
  .split(" ")
return myArr
.map((arrr) => parseInt(arrr,10))
}

console.log(steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]))
```

Comment: Where does the `2` in your expected result come from?

Comment: why not recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Just use recursion. No need to worry about types when you do not change them.

```js
function cleanUp(arr, out=[]) {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        cleanUp(item, out);
    } else {
      out.push(item);
    } 
  });
  return out;
}

console.log(cleanUp([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the vlaue is NaN and default to zero

`isNaN(arrr)?0:parseInt(arrr,10))`

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  
  let myArr= arr 
  .join(" ")
  .replace(/[\s+\W+]/g," ")
  .replace(/\s+/g," ")
  .split(" ")
return myArr
.map((arrr) => isNaN(arrr)?0:parseInt(arrr,10))
}

console.log(steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]))
```

Comment: your output does not match what OP wants

Comment: Can you explain what isNaN does? thank you.

Comment: documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN